# ios extension use NSURLSession background upload after download will delay

Tags: ios, upload, download, nsurlsession, ios8-share-extension

I want to do upload the data that downloaded from the server in the share extension, but the upload task is delayed, it will proceed in the next time I push post button in my share extension. I found this message in Document describes "discretionary", does it mean that the upload task is started when the APP is in the background status, so the system might delay do upload.

> For transfers started while your app is in the background, the system always starts transfers at its discretion—in other words, the system assumes this property is YES and ignores any value you specified.

Here are the codes:

```
- (void)didSelectPost {
        NSURLSession *session = [self configureSession];
        NSString *downLoadStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://apis.live.net/v5.0/%@/content?access_token=%@", [shareProfile objectForKey:@“PATH”], accesToken];
        mDownloadTask = [session downloadTaskWithURL:downUrl];
        [mDownloadTask resume];
        [self.extensionContext completeRequestReturningItems:[self.extensionContext inputItems] completionHandler:nil];
}


- (NSURLSession *) configureSession {

    static NSURLSession *session = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        NSURLSessionConfiguration* config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:@"com.test.background_shareext"];
                // To access the shared container you set up, use the sharedContainerIdentifier property on your configuration object.
        config.sharedContainerIdentifier = @"group.test.background”;
        session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
    });
    return session;
}

- (void) URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location{
    if (location != nil) {
        NSString *str = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[location path] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
        char *utfString = [[@"" stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@\n%@\n", str, @"test"] UTF8String];
        NSData *uploadData = [NSData dataWithBytes:utfString length:strlen(utfString)];
       NSString *uploadUrlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://apis.live.net/v5.0/%@/files/%@?suppress_response_codes=true&overwrite=true&access_token=%@", path, file, accesToken];
       NSURL                     *uploadUrl                  = [NSURL URLWithString:uploadUrlStr];
       NSMutableURLRequest *uploadReq = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:uploadUrl cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:HTTP_REQUEST_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL];
      [uploadReq setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"];
      [uploadReq setHTTPBody:uploadData];
      NSURLSession *session = [self configureSession];
      NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [session uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:uploadReq];
      [uploadTask resume];
    }else{
        NSLog(@"download task location is nil");
    }
}
```

Update:

After I share some times, the download task might stop, and runs until I share later.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Comment: Sorry for troubling you, spell mistake... I will pay attention next time.